# Difference in Forecast and Fitted method in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following piece of code:

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(1234)
y <- ts(sort(rnorm(30)), start = 1978, frequency = 1) # annual data
fcasts <- numeric(10)
for (i in 1:10) { # start rolling forecast
  # start from 1997, every time one more year included
  win.y <- window(y, end = 1996 + i) 
  fit <- auto.arima(win.y)
  fcasts[i] <- forecast(fit, h = 1)$mean
}
train <- window(y,end=1997)
fit<- auto.arima(train)
refit <- Arima(y, model=fit)
fc <- window(fitted(refit), start=1998)
```

I thought both should give same results, but why fcasts and fc give different results?

Comment: Yes it does, it was just for the data I was using, which is replaced by dummy data here.

Comment: This question has already been adequately answered [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/218001).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you shorten you code, it becomes:

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(1234)
y <- ts(sort(rnorm(30)), start = 1978, frequency = 1) # annual data
fcasts <- numeric(10)
for (i in 1:10) {
  fcasts[i] <- forecast(auto.arima(window(y, end = 1996 + i) ), h = 1)$mean
}
fc <- window(fitted(Arima(y, model = auto.arima(window(y, end = 1997)))), start = 1998)
```

And here you can see, that `fc` always relies on the constant `auto.arima(window(y, end = 1997))`, where the values in `fcasts` rely on the changing `auto.arima(window(y, end = 1996 + i))`. Because both forcasts for 1998 are based on the identical model for 1997, they are identical. But the others are not.

To adress the comment whether both models give the same result:

```
fcasts <- numeric(10)
fc <- numeric(10)

for (i in 1:10) {
  fcasts[i] <- forecast(auto.arima(window(y, end = 1996 + i) ), h = 1)$mean
  fc <- window(fitted.Arima(Arima(y, model = auto.arima(window(y, end = 1996 + i)))), start = 1998)[i]
}

fcasts-fc # is identical (beside very small numerical differences of `e-14`).
```

Comment: For the first (n-1) terms difference was subtle, and I thought if they are the same then I can avoid the loop, which is computationally more efficient, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: So fitting the same model will give identical results?

Comment: @Vic, if you change the generation of `fc` in a manner that you fit the same `auto.arima` model: yes, they provide identical results. I added this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the difference between forecast and fitted pointed by @Billywob in the comments, your loop is using different models to forecast:

```
fcasts <- numeric(10)
modls<-list()
for (i in 1:10) { # start rolling forecast
  # start from 1997, every time one more year included
  win.y <- window(y, end = 1996 + i) 
  fit <- auto.arima(win.y)
  modls[[i]]<- names(fit$coef)
  fcasts[i] <- forecast(fit, h = 1)$mean
}

> modls
[[1]]
[1] "ar1"

[[2]]
[1] "ar1"

[[3]]
[1] "ar1"

[[4]]
[1] "ar1"

[[5]]
[1] "ar1"

[[6]]
[1] "ar1"

[[7]]
[1] "ar1"

[[8]]
[1] "ar1"

[[9]]
[1] "ar1"   "drift"

[[10]]
[1] "ar1"   "drift"
```

and your fitted only uses one model.

```
> names(fit$coef)
[1] "ar1"
```