# One step-ahead forecasts in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, state-space-models

I would like to compare one-step ahead forecasts on a given time series for ARIMA and UCM (using KFAS library). I have split my time series in train and validation, that I will use to understand which model performs better.

After reading the anwswer to this post: [Difference between first one-step ahead forecast and first forecast from fitted model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217955/difference-between-first-one-step-ahead-forecast-and-first-forecast-from-fitted/511119#511119), I understood the following explanation for Arima:

> So fitted(fit) gives one-step forecasts of observations 1, 2, ... It
> is possible to produce a "forecast" for observation 1 as a forecast is
> simply the expected value of that observation given the model and any
> preceding history.
>
> fitted(refit) gives one-step forecasts of observations 401, 402, ....
> So it uses the model estimated on observations 1...400, but it uses
> the data from time 401...500.

What I don't understand is how to make one-step forecasts on observations 401, 402, .. using data from time 1.. 400 and (possibly?) the calculated forecasts up to previous time. I want to pretend not to know data 401..500 and compare the one-step forecasts with them.

Comment: Welcome to CV botti23!

Answer (score 0):

(hi, i cant comment so

1.
arima (1,0,0) = ar (1) need 1 previous observation
ar (2) need 2 previous observations

2.
arima do calculate with training data value of coeficients
(for ar (1) its like: intercept and ar1

you can calculate coeficients arima(data[1:400]
or you can also arima(data[1:472]

**(1) so you always need previous (current data) to make 1 step prediction**

**(2) you can use the same values of coeficients or you can update them as new data are comming**

Comment: Thank you for your help. Practically speaking, should I loop 100 times, applying forecast using the previously trained cofficients , h=1, and the train timeseries followed by the already forecasted observations?

I tried this:

predictions <- c(rep(NA,len_validation)) # last 100 observations

temp_ts <- ts_train # first 400 observations

for (i in 1:len_validation) {
  temp_mod<- Arima(temp_ts, model = mod1.5)
  predictions[i] <- forecast(temp_mod, h = 1)$mean
  temp_ts <- ts(c(temp_ts,predictions[i]))
}

but it seems to return the same as forecast(mod1.5, h=len_validation)

Comment: (i didnt work with re-using model..i can onlyguess: if at 1:400 , prediction for h=100 ....for example 500th data point - is 100% exactly same as model trained 1:499 for h=1.....it tells that data are "very deterministic" ... how can i guess weather for 100th day,..with same precision as waited 99 days and guess tomorrow .... but i checked https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.13/topics/Arima and it is possible - i think it points, that data are strong deterministic, cycled....if its for school, i personaly would mention both results and point to good data stability : )